# Indexes is created by itself in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, indexing

Could you help please. I'm a newbie in PostgreSQL. I use pgAdmin for management and I don't understand all of my tables have ~7-10 indexes, but I've not created them.

E.g. in screenshot. If I try to detect unused indexes all of them exist in this list. How is this indexes created in my DB? Is this normal or not?

[image]

Comment: The only(!) index Postgres creates automatically is one for a primary key or unique constraint. Every other index was created by you (or some script you ran).

Comment: Hm very interesting. Maybe can pgadmin or django when it aplies migrations create this indexes?

Comment: pgAdmin will only do things if you tell it to. So most probably this django thing if you didn't run anything manually

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much. 
I will pay attention to Django.

Comment: I've understood It's django. This Indexes is created when I use in models models.ForeignKey without db_index=False. Default is db_index=True